# Create new template to surround multi-lined string with quotes and a plus

Tags: java, string, eclipse, quotes, surround

So I tried to create a surround-with-template in Eclipse that is supposed to surround a selected text block with quotations and only if the text block has multiple lines, it should put a + in front of these.

i.e.:

```
"string"
+"string"
```

selected_line should not be used because the string might be shared with other code in the same line. Is this even possible?

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible due to the distinction of the cases single vs. multi line. But you can implement a _Quick Fix_ for that. Or you can use the key sequence Ctrl+X, `"` and Ctrl+V which adds the `+` at the end of the previous line and which also adds line break characters (and which requires _Window Preferences: Java > Editor > Typing: In string literals > Escape text when pasting into a string literal_ to be enabled).

Comment: oh wow I didn't know that :) thanks